# Member Distinguished name does not get deleted from Group's unique member attribute even if member has been deleted in Oracle directory server

Tags: oracle, ldap, directoryservices, ldap-query

I am working with Oracle directory server using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols
library.When I make a user member of a Group, that member's DN is still in that group's uniqueMember attribute even if I have deleted that member.Please guide me how could those redundant DN's could be removed from ldap server.